# Background color not showing in IE10/IE11 during the print

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Internet Explorer 10 and 11 are not showing the white background color while printing neither the box shadow.

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class="note">
    <span>Clears buy point in weak post-holiday trade.</span>
</div>
```

**CSS Code:**

```
body {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.note {
    border: 0px solid rgb(64, 64, 64);
    background-color: #ffffff;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    top: 40px;
    left: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
    color: rgb(64, 64, 64);
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: default;
    opacity: 1;
    background-position: initial initial;
    background-repeat: initial initial;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 9px 20px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.8);
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 9px 20px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.8);
    box-shadow: 3px 9px 20px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.8);
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
span {
    padding 5px;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: When you linked the .css file did you use `media=screen`?

Comment: Sure I link it using `<style type="text/css" media="print">` @jason-aller

Comment: It's intentional: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/296326

Answer (score 3):

When I load it with IE 11 the output I see with print preview depends on if I've turned on `Print Background Colors and Images` under options on the print preview. I did the testing using jsfiddle.net and wrapped the supplied css in `@media print { ... }`. The output then looks fine, the behavior is browser configuration driven.

http://jsfiddle.net/LFfrV/1/ of what I was using to test.

Comment: Yes it's related to browser configuration. Is there any to force IE and print backgrounds like `-webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;` ?

Comment: Is a sistem restart needed? Because in my case is not working